# Android - Disable Password hint

Tags: android

How to disable password hint while using softkeyboard in Android applications???

Answer (score 4):

Mention the **`android:inputType`** attribute inside your EditText:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Can this be done programmatically??The application does not uses xml file rather this is using json and javascript together for user inputs.

Comment: I have tried the modification its not working.Can there be any other way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I have come up with.

1. Create a new class that `extends TextWatcher`
2. `@Override public void beforeTextChanged()` to capture the new `CharSequence`
3. Store the new `CharSequence` privately so you know what text is in there.
4. Replace the text in the `EditText` with X number of password bullets (•)
5. Add the watcher to your `EditText` with `pwEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PassWatcher());`

Hope that helps