# Problem with android password field, not hiding the last character typed

Tags: android, android-edittext

In Android, I create a password field like this:

```
    EditText text = new EditText(context);
    text.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Or like this, which seems to do the same thing:

```
    EditText text = new EditText(context);
    text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

I get a nice password field except for the last character typed by the user. It's visible on the screen for a few seconds before beeing masked with a dot.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Do you know how to fix this behaviour please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is expected behavior. With the soft keyboards on most devices, it is valuable feedback that they are typing the password correctly.

For a list of all of the different inputTypes you can specify and how they change the EditText,

see [android inputTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) .

Also, it is possible to change this behavior by implementing your own `TransformationMethod` and setting it via `setTransformationMethod()`, but I would not recommend doing that. Users will expect the behavior you are seeing and by changing your app, you'll be providing an inconsistent user experience.

also check this [android article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29)

Comment: Ok, I don't like this very much but since it's the Android way, I will not change it. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @Joel, Well, the last char should turn into dot in several seconds. At least I can see this on my device.

Comment: This also happens on other mobile smartphone/tablet platforms such as iOS.  It's really a standard expected behaviour for most users.

Comment: Expected behavior does not warrant complacency. The Android OS is also being used on Tablets and other devices with real keyboards where screen-looking security can also be a concern. The second-highest answer to this question should absolutely be the accepted one, and it's an embarrassment to StackOverflow that this one is, instead.

Comment: @codetaku, chill man. It's my opinion that the current behavior is the expected behavior for nearly all cases. It's important for new mobile developers to understand why they see this (expected) behavior. If you have a specific case that warrants changing that behavior, then implement the answer below. It's not an embarrassment to StackOverflow. If you feel so strongly about it, go open a bug against AOSP.

Answer (score 10):

Implementation of TransformationMethod to hide last char typed in password:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // example of usage
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.password)).setTransformationMethod(new HiddenPassTransformationMethod());
}

private class HiddenPassTransformationMethod implements TransformationMethod {

    private char DOT = '\u2022';

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(final CharSequence charSequence, final View view) {
        return new PassCharSequence(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChanged(final View view, final CharSequence charSequence, final boolean b, final int i,
                               final Rect rect) {
        //nothing to do here
    }

    private class PassCharSequence implements CharSequence {

        private final CharSequence charSequence;

        public PassCharSequence(final CharSequence charSequence) {
            this.charSequence = charSequence;
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(final int index) {
            return DOT;
        }

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return charSequence.length();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(final int start, final int end) {
            return new PassCharSequence(charSequence.subSequence(start, end));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem after needing to implement a pin-code type user interface.  After the user entered 1 number (1:1 relationship between EditTexts and pin numbers for a total of 4  EditTexts) the password would remain "in the open".  My solution was to implement a TextWatcher that replaced the input with bullets (•'s).

[See the full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151836/android-disable-password-hint/8525612#8525612)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issues, in my case there was 3 edit text each edit text can have maximum 4 digit number for Aadhaar number. I used numberPassword input type.

When user type Aadhaar number very fast first edit text last text 4th was not hiding because I am changing focus when 4 digit completed. I have added text watcher.

I got solution at the end of last edit text when 4 digit completed I requestFocus for all 3 edit text one by one.

[image]

Solution :

```
  @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        if (getBinding().edtFirstFourNumber.getText().toString().length() == 4 && getBinding().edtMiddleFourNumber.getText().toString().length() == 4 && getBinding().edtLastFourNumber.getText().toString().length() == 4) {
            //  getBinding().homeProceed.setAlpha(1f);
            getBinding().homeProceed.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color_ffffff));
            getBinding().homeProceed.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //  getBinding().homeProceed.setAlpha(0.5f);
            getBinding().homeProceed.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color_4090BE));
            getBinding().homeProceed.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (getBinding().edtFirstFourNumber.length() == 4) {
            getBinding().edtMiddleFourNumber.requestFocus();
        }
        if (getBinding().edtMiddleFourNumber.length() == 4) {
            getBinding().edtLastFourNumber.requestFocus();
        }
        if (getBinding().edtLastFourNumber.length() == 4) {
            getBinding().edtFirstFourNumber.requestFocus();
            getBinding().edtMiddleFourNumber.requestFocus();
            getBinding().edtLastFourNumber.requestFocus();
            CommonUtils.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
        }

    }
```