# Why does the password field in Android show the character first and then gets masked?

Tags: android, passwords

While am entering the password in my application in the password field, t first shows the character and then change. My system configuration is less, I have 1GB Ram and dual core processor -  Is that is the reason am seeing the character? Is there other field to be choosen to get like other login pages.

Comment: Sorry, have read your question two times and haven't understand anything

Comment: Following post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360222/problem-with-android-password-field-not-hiding-the-last-character-typed

Comment: while am entering the password in my application in the password field. Then it first shows the character and then change. Explore this to get the responses , If u have code why dont u share it?

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is only the Android behavior *if* the user settings are “show passwords.” The user can disable this, globally. (Or was it that the user would need to explicitly enable this feature? I don't think my device ever showed passwords.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a error. It is behaviour of the password field to ensure you are entering correct characters. Its same for device also.

Answer (score 1):

May be similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360222/problem-with-android-password-field-not-hiding-the-last-character-typed)

Actually this not an error. You also face this into the device also when you type your password in the password field like login into any chat app or any web site.

This the behavior of this field to ensure the user that he type the correct character

It is possible to change this behavior by implementing your own TransformationMethod and setting it via setTransformationMethod(), but I would not recommend doing that. Users will expect the behavior you are seeing and by changing your app, you'll be providing an inconsistent user experience.

[Android Reference Manual on this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29)