# Android Hide password

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to hide my password as dot and it happens but problem is it hiding after a second i just want to make a dot as i type i should not show the word i typed there....
here is my code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:password="true" >
```

Comment: You can change this behavior from the setting of the device under security session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with android password field, not hiding the last character typed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360222/problem-with-android-password-field-not-hiding-the-last-character-typed)

Comment: @Ravi, programmatically it is possible, but not expected. See the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360222/problem-with-android-password-field-not-hiding-the-last-character-typed

Answer (score 0):

I found two different solutions, try both of one:

1) Remove `android:inputType="textPassword"` from your xml file and instead, in set it in java:

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

As you're typing in that edit field, you don't see each character in plain text before it turns into a password dot. Also when making input in fullscreen, the dots will not appear, but the passoword in clear text.

2) Leave `android:inputType="textPassword"` in your xml. In Java, ALSO set the typeface and passwordMethod:

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_text);
password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

This approach gave me the hint font I wanted AND gives me the behavior I want with the password dots.

Hope it will help you!...

Comment: Nope its not helping still showing test i entered there and after that showing dot