# How can I fill editText with password chars, so there are hidden chars in there

Tags: android, xml

I have a design where the editText should have some hidden chars set as password. And after clicking edittext, they should disappear.

[image]

Just like this, the circles should be there however once clicked or when eye icon(for making it visible) is clicked, nothing should be there.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395030/android-hide-password) may help you with your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch between hide and view password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685790/how-to-switch-between-hide-and-view-password)

Comment: I guess I did not formulate my question properly. What I want is some dummy text in password field, but it should be with dots. As soon as the user clicks the editText, those circles should disappear

Comment: So user can type his/her password. The circles are just part of design. But I cannot think of way of implementing it

Comment: Benazir Sh the answer is below check it

Comment: What I want is some dummy text in password field, but it should be with dots. - you can set hint for this in the edit text

Comment: hint is appearing is letters, not in dots

Comment: just set special characters as hint - android:hint="•••••••"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these 2 lines in your EditText code;

```
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="●●●●●●
```

Comment: My question is how can I set 6 chars like dots as hint? And when clicked, those circles should disappear. It is just a matter of design

Comment: Those hint chars should be displayed as textPassword

Comment: When I add hint to my editText with inputType password, the text is visisble, it is not hidden in dots

Answer (score 0):

android:hint="•••••••"
decided to do so

Comment: Glad to see you found out the solution