# Unable to disable android password suggestion

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

When i try to enter some text into password field i will get possible suggestions . how can i avoid this .I want to disable the keyboard suggestion on typing. If this question is repeated can anyone suggest me. 
in using 
'android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"' in password field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Multiline & No autosuggest in EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653271/android-multiline-no-autosuggest-in-edittext)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151836/android-disable-password-hint/8525612#8525612

Answer (score 0):

You could set `TextFieldName.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` to an empty listener, that ought to solve your problem

Comment: Null won't do the trick, you'll have to make a new TextWatcher and then not use it.